# How to test if a function runs without failure or returns a specific value

Tags: python, unit-testing

I just need to test whether the function runs without failure or
test whether the value returned is one of:

```
('NDP', None) or ('CPC', None) or ('GREEN', None) or ('LIBERAL', None)
```

---

```
def test_single_zero_ballot(self):
    self.assertEqual(voting_systems.voting_irv({('NDP','CPC','LIBERAL','GREEN'):0}),
                     (('NDP', None) or ('CPC', None) or ('GREEN', None) or ('LIBERAL', None)),
    'Fails to run when there is a single ballot with zero votes')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `assertIn`, as you're checking if the value is one of a few values:

```
def test_single_zero_ballot(self):
    valid_values = [('NDP', None), ('CPC', None), ('GREEN', None), ('LIBERAL', None)]    
    self.assertIn(voting_systems.voting_irv({('NDP','CPC','LIBERAL','GREEN'):0}),
                     valid_values,
    'Fails to run when there is a single ballot with zero votes')
```

See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn) for the full details.